# Container exited with code 0 when run from docker-compose

Tags: python, django, bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a container from  docker file.

```
**docker-compose.yml**
    services:
        djangoapp:
            build: .
            volumes:
              - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
            ports:
              - 8000:8000

**Dockerfile** this is entry in Docker file
    ENTRYPOINT bash start.sh
**start.sh**
    #!/bin/bash
    ## run gunicorn in background......
    gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000  hello_django.wsgi:application &
```

when i build image from same **Dockerfile**, its working fine.
when i launch from docker-compose up, it shows **exited with code 0**.
**I wanted to know the reason why my docker exited (Exited (0) 18 seconds ago)** ??

Comment: Can you update you Dockerfile in the question?

Comment: Also check logs with `docker-compose logs djangoapp`

Answer (score 5):

Your `start.sh` script launches some background processes, then reaches the end, and exits (successfully, so with status code 0).  When the `start.sh` script exits, since its the container's `ENTRYPOINT`, the container exits with the same status code.

There needs to be some process running as a foreground process, and the container will keep running as long as that process is.  In your case that's the GUnicorn process, and you can specify that as the image's `CMD` in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000 hello_django.wsgi:application
```

If the only thing in your `start.sh` script is running that line, you can delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line.  If not, change it to run `exec "$@"` as the last line (to run the `CMD`), and change the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` line to JSON-array syntax:

```sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
CMD gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000 hello_django.wsgi:application
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# ... do other pre-launch setup ...
# Run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

(I would avoid running background processes in a container startup script: nothing will monitor or restart those, and you can wind up in a state where you have a half-running container, or where you unnecessarily need to restart some things because others got updates.  If you need multiple processes running, try to arrange them to run in separate containers; if you only need one, run it as the foreground process.)

Comment: if you think that it's because the background process completes & exits then it should be the same for the normal docker build & run isn't it ? As per the question, normal docker run works as expected but only when done via compose results in this. Any thoughts?

Comment: The background process isn't relevant: you get to the end of the script successfully, the script exits, and the container exits.  I'm not sure why it would be different with the Compose setup vs. otherwise; potentially you're running different code if the `volumes:` are overwriting the entrypoint script.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by bringing background process into foreground.
When we put     `gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000  hello_django.wsgi:application &` in background it will keep running but main process (pid 0) which is created by ENTRYPOINT/CMD will exit with code zero (All instructions executed successfully.)

Keeping this process in foreground, or if in background bring into foreground will solve the issue.

1. `gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000  hello_django.wsgi:application`
   This will keep running and will not let pid 0 die (because this "instruction is still running / not finished processing" so PID 0 will wait for this to finish)

Or

2. `gunicorn --chdir hello --bind :8000  hello_django.wsgi:application &`
   then bring background process into foreground.

   fg %1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it, which is different that other answers here:

I use the docker-compose command line option called `--exit-code-from`.

If you have a `docker-compose.yml` with a few serviices and 1 e2e test container that you need the exit code from, then just do this:

In this context, something like this:

```
docker-compose up --exit-code-from e2e-tests
```

Example project here, with screenshots: https://github.com/djangofan/karate-test-prime-example

Share
Edit
Delete